# Class Factory Methods implementation

Tags: objective-c

So I am working my way through the Apple documentation of objective-C (before jumping into iphone development). One of the exercises states that I should create a designated initializer  (with 3 params) and suitable factory method.

Now I did this based on my understanding but I am unable to implement the factory method because I dont know if I should use alloc and init within its implementation or not?

the exercise:

> Declare and implement a new designated initializer used to create an
>   XYZPerson using a specified first name, last name and date of birth,
>   along with a suitable class factory method. Don’t forget to override
>   init to call the designated initializer.

The code:

```
//.h 

-(id)initWithNameAndDob:(NSString *)fName last:(NSString *)lName birth:(NSDate *) dob;

//.m
-(id)initWithNameAndDob:(NSString *)fName last:(NSString *)lName birth:(NSDate *)dob{
    self = [super init];
    return [self initWithNameAndDob:fName last:lName birth:dob];
}
```

something missing in implementation?

thank you,

Comment: Factory method begins with +, and instance method with -.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Declare and implement a new designated initializer used to create an XYZPerson using a specified first name, last name and date of birth...

You are correct in the declaration but your implementation is recursive, since it's calling itself. Do something like

```
//.h
-(id)initWithNameAndDob:(NSString *)fName last:(NSString *)lName birth:(NSDate *) dob;
//.m
-(id)initWithNameAndDob:(NSString *)fName last:(NSString *)lName birth:(NSDate *)dob{
    if(self = [super init]) {
        // use the parameters to do something, eg.
        _fName = fName; // assuming you have an ivar called _fName 
        _lName = lName; // assuming you have an ivar called _lName
        _dob = dob; // assuming you have an ivar called _dob
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then

> ...along with a suitable class factory method.

A factory method is a class method that produces an instance of the object. The most common implementation is to have it to allocate and initialize a new instance of the object and return it.

```
//.h
+(instancetype)personWithNameAndDob:(NSString *)fName last:(NSString *)lName birth:(NSDate *) dob {


//.m
+(instancetype)personWithNameAndDob:(NSString *)fName last:(NSString *)lName birth:(NSDate *) dob {
return [[XYZPerson alloc] initWithNameAndDob:fName last:lName birth:dob];
}
```

Finally

> Don’t forget to override init to call the designated initializer.

Since your designed initializer is `initWithNameAndDob:last:birth:` your `init` implementation must call it. The parameters of the designed initializer have to be a reasonable default, in this case `nil` is fine.

```
-(id)init {
     return [self initWithNameAndDob:nil last:nil birth:nil];
 }
```

As a final remark I'd like to point out that your naming convention for the initializer is not that good. A more suitable and readable one would be

```
-(id)initWithFirstName:(NSString *)fName lastName:(NSString *)lName dateOfBirth:(NSDate *) dob;
```

Comment: thanks v.much for explanation. the naming conventions was just to get a testing out of the code. otherwise more descriptive. I dont understad why you declare -(id)initWithNameAndDob then you do +(XYZPerson *)WithNameAndDob? both of them will be in .m file.

Comment: In your .h you (can) have both the `initWith...` and the `personWith` declaration. The implementation of both goes in the .m file. Also check my updated answer since I found a big mistake in your code and some typo in my signatures ;)

Comment: :O what was the big mistake?! I am assuming you using the word "can" means it is not must so I can just do with initWith?

Comment: An Objective-C factory method is just a wrapper for `alloc` and `init`, so it should return the same type, `id`. The method's name should begin with a description of the object being returned, so in this case the name of the method should be something like `+personWithFirstName:lastName:dateOfBirth`. Note that method names should begin with a lowercase letter, and should generally avoid including abbreviations. Formal acronyms (e.g. **HTML**) are acceptable, but should be properly capitalized.

Comment: usually I make visible only the factory methods, since they are easier to use (the client does not need to take care of allocating the instance). The error is the implementation of your `initWith...`

Comment: @jlehr that's not properly correct. The return type depends on the context. `id` is mandatory only in case of a hierarchy of classes, but if that's not the case returning the actual type is much better.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Please cite a reason rather than just stating as a  subjective impression that using a return type other than `id` is 'much better.'

Comment: The compiler will know the type and it can help you in catching errors at compiler time. Using `id` for `init` is a necessary "workaround" not a desirable feature.

Comment: @Gabriele Petronella `-(id)init { return [self initWithNameAndDob:nil last:nil birth:nil]; }` why we do that ? `return [self initWithNameAndDob:nil last:nil birth:nil];` I don't understand.Thank you

Comment: what don't you understand?

Answer (score 5):

Excellent explanation by Gabriele Petronella but there is problem.

```
+(instancetype)personWithNameAndDob:(NSString *)fName last:(NSString *)lName birth:(NSDate *) dob {
return [[XYZPerson alloc] initWithNameAndDob:fName last:lName birth:dob];
}

It should be replaced with 
+(instancetype)personWithNameAndDob:(NSString *)fName last:(NSString *)lName birth:(NSDate *) dob {
return [[self alloc] initWithNameAndDob:fName last:lName birth:dob];
}
```

**Rule:**
Don’t refer to your own class by name, because you don’t know what the concrete class will be. You’ll inadvertently chop off the ability to extend and override the class through subclassing. Instead,
To allocate an instance in a class’s factory method: [self alloc]
**Reference:**
http://qualitycoding.org/factory-method/

Comment: i.AsifNoor is correct. In the examples if you don't use self then your XYZShoutingPerson won't work properly.