# How to declare a class factory method in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, factory

I am a newbie with Objective C programming.

My first steps to learn Objective C is to read the PDF "Programming with Objective C" from the Apple Developers site.

At the end of every chapter there are exercises to make. Chapter 1 has 4 questions. The first 3 questions are not so dificult to make. But the 4th question I can't figure it out what the anwser is.

The question is:

> Add a declaration for a class factory method, called "Person". Don't worry about implementation this method until the next chapter.

I hope that anybody can and will help me.

Thank you
Carlos Wiesemann

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class Factory Methods implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14092222/class-factory-methods-implementation)

Answer (score 1):

Take another look at the section just before the exercises, [Objective-C Classes Are also Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH3-SW18). That section talks about how classes themselves are objects that can have methods separate from the methods that an instance of the class has. When the question asks for a "class factory" method, it means a class method that creates a new instance of that class, just like the string methods in the linked section.

Comment: @weiseman I would also add this from **Concepts in Objective-C**: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassFactoryMethods/ClassFactoryMethods.html

Answer (score 1):

Class method declarations look just like instance methods, except they are prefixed with a plus sign instead of a minus sign. For example,suppose you have a class named Car
 let’s add the following class-level method to Car.h:

```
+ (void)setDefaultModel:(NSString *)aModel;
```

Comment: Thus the answer of the (my) question is: + (id) person; i really don't understand this.

Comment: you can also define like this +(void)person;